# how could I make a button redirect to another page in play

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I make a simple app  in play but I faced a problem when I press the button It didn't respond what could I do?

this is the scala file & I want the button to take the 3 values & return a new value in a new form

```
@(solutionForm: Form[Socrates])
@import helper._
@main(title = "form 1") {

    @form(action = routes.Application.solve, args = 'id -> "solutionform") {

    @inputText(field = solutionForm("a"),args = '_label -> " a ="
    )@inputText(field = solutionForm("b"),args = '_label -> "b ="
    )@inputText(field = solutionForm("c"),args = '_label -> "c ="
    )    } 
    <input type="submit" >
}
```

The new form is:

```
@(man : String )
@main("solution") {
    <h3>the solution for the previous  equation is   @man  </h3> 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button should be inside form tag to work.

```
@form() {
  <input type="submit">
}
```

Comment: plz , this doesn't work  why ???


s = form.data().get("b");
            b = Integer.valueOf(s);



[NumberFormatException: null]